# How to exclude a directory from redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a subdomain, like http://subdomain.example.com and for reasons I redirect the whole subdoamin to http://example.com/subdomain/

For Google I need to access the sitemap directory with the sitemaps file which look like this: http://subdomain.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap01.xml

My htaccess redirects the sitemap urls to the main URL (http://example.com/subdomain/).

My htaccess looks like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/

RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+-[0-9]+)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]+)$ appsite.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

I searched the net for solutions, but can't find anything, I could use.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the URL doesn't begin with `sitemap`. Try to apply this RewriteRule instead (**but** remove your `RewriteCond`).

```
RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap)(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/$1
```

If this still doesn't work, add this entry after your RewriteCond (but use your current RewriteRule, not mine)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.*$
```

Comment: I added  another two lines to the original post, because there are some other redirects happening and maybe that prevents it to work.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. If I use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap)(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/` it is the same as now. If I use only your line of code, it redirects indefinitely.

Comment: @Hunnen Sorry for that infinite redirect. Edited - just tried that on my domain and it worked.

Comment: When I apply the code, I get redirected on the site normally, but for the sitemaps I get redirected here: `http://example.com/subdomain/subdomain/sitemaps/sitemap01.xml` where subdomain of course the same is, only twice.

Comment: @Hunnen I have tried that without RewriteCond you mentioned. Have you tried without it too?

Comment: @Hunnen Have you tried without your RewriteCond entry?

Comment: Nothing works. I tried every possible variation.
Thanks for your help! Now I know the logic, maybe I can figure something out.

Comment: @Hunnen Have you also tried removing your own regex? Because, how could that happen, it works for me...

Comment: It works now. Actually my code works. I just had to add a `$1` behind the URL. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/$1`

Comment: @Hunnen Oh so you forgot it! Nice that it works now :)